# Unable change style svg

Tags: svg, node-red

I need help,
I need to pass style arguments from nodered to uibuilder to change the color of a rectangle for example

on a function I wrote this code:

```
msg.topic = "CStatus"
switch (msg.payload) {

case "RUN":
    msg.colorStatus = "fill = #00b050; stroke = #001e46; stroke-width = 5";
    break;
    
"False" case:
    msg.colorStatus = "red";
    break;
    
default:
    msg.colorStatus = "#00b050";
    break;
}
msg.statusColMachine = msg.colorStatus;
return msg;
```

i created the variables on index.js

```
uibuilder.onChange('msg', function(newVal){
            //console.info('[indexjs:uibuilder.onChange] msg received from Node-RED server:', newVal)
            vueApp.msgRecvd = newVal
                if (newVal.topic == "Status"){
                vueApp.Status = newVal.statusMachine;
                }
            if (newVal.topic == "CStatus"){
                vueApp.colorStatus = newVal.statusColMachine;
                }
        })
```

and put this code on index.html

```
  <rect 
    style = {{colorStatus}}
    id="status" 
    height="113.33333" 
    width="500" 
    y="1306.33334" 
    x="2033" 
    />
```

But the black rectangle appears.

If I do an inspection from Chrome

```
<rect id = "status" height = "113.33333" width = "500" y = "1306.33334" x = "2033"> </rect>
```

Where am I wrong?
Maybe the problem is that it doesn't hook correctly to the html attribute?

Answer (score 2):

For a start,

- `"False" case:` should presumably be `case "False":` and
- `style = {{colorStatus}}` should be `style="{{colorStatus}}"`.

Also, the `style` attribute takes CSS properties, so if you are setting `style={{colorStatus}}`, then

```
msg.colorStatus = "fill = #00b050; stroke = #001e46; stroke-width = 5";
```

should presumably be

```
msg.colorStatus = "fill: #00b050; stroke: #001e46; stroke-width: 5";
```

and

```
msg.colorStatus = "red";
```

should presumably be

```
msg.colorStatus = "fill: red";
```

and

```
msg.colorStatus = "#00b050";
```

should presumably be

```
msg.colorStatus = "fill: #00b050";
```

Although there is also a lot of your code missing. So it's not exactly clear what is supposed to happen.